# Sending image files using GNS3

Tags: cisco, router, ipv4, ipv6, gns3

I had built a network using GNS3, this network contains a lot of routers,
the problem is:

I want to send an image file between these routers using GNS3

is there any way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to send the same IOS code image? What have you tried?

Comment: No...
I want to upload then send a normal image from a router to another router

Comment: If you mean pictures, then routers have no use for pictures. Applications that run on your hosts may use pictures, but applications and host/server configurations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a vpc into the same network in gns3 and then you can upload anything to the switches. Or you can use scp from one switch to another as long as your L3 connectivity is proper between them.